# Can org-agenda view specific years?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Issuing `M-x org-agenda a v y` allows me to view my agenda for the *current* year. Is it possible to view my agenda for *next* year? More generally, is it possible to view my agenda for a *specific* year or for a specified block of time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The year (as well as day, month, week etc.) can take a prefix argument specifying the period you want to view.  To view a specific year (e.g. 2017) pass the year using `C-u` while in the agenda: `C-u 2017 v y`.

This works by calling the function `org-agenda-year-view`:

> (org-agenda-year-view &optional YEAR)
>
> Switch to yearly view for agenda.
>   With argument YEAR, switch to that year.  Years ranging from 70
>   years ago to 30 years in the future can also be written as
>   2-digit years.

If you want to view this frequently you can save it as a custom agenda command.  The period shown is controlled by `org-agneda-span` (how much to show) and `org-agenda-start-day` (when to start).  For example:

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("y" "2017 agenda"
               agenda ""
               ((org-agenda-span 'year)
                (org-agenda-start-day "2017-01-01")
               )))
```